Eclipse Ditto - Retrieving Thing Data in incoming payload mapper
Imagine the following scenario:
A device:

when coming online, sends a payload with the registration timestamp and the sampling rate of its sensors
After that, it sends payloads with sensor samples and the sample number.

For the second type of payloads, is it possible in the incoming payload mappers to retrieve the sampling rate and registration timestamp to calculate the sample timestamps?
After reading the documentation I haven't discovered any way to retrieve a specific thing in the mappers. If not, what would be a good way to approach this problem?
I have tried some javascript incoming payload mappers without luck.
